# How to create an NSString with one random letter?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I need to create an NSString that has a single random uppercase letter.

I can get random int's fine, and I could construct a C string from it and then make the NSString, but I imagine there has to be a better and more cocoa-ish way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just make an NSString containing what you consider to be letters and pull a random character from it. Here's an example category:

```
@implementation NSString(RandomLetter)
- (NSString *)randomLetter {
    return [self substringWithRange:[self rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:random()%[self length]]];
}
@end
```

(You'll need to `srandom(time())` at some point, obviously. Maybe include an initialize method in your category.)

Comment: With A-Z, this approach will work great.

If you're not going to limit your domain to something like A-Z, you need to be careful with this technique. What the user thinks of as a single character might not be a single unichar.

Comment: There comes a point where the idea of a character is ambiguous. I've changed it so that it explicitly uses Cocoa's support for composed character sequences.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to use a c string so that you can use an explicit encoding. Here's an example of that:

```
NSInteger MyRandomIntegerBetween(NSInteger min, NSInteger max) {
    return (random() % (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

NSString *MyStringWithRandomUppercaseLetter(void) {
    char string[2] = {0, 0};
    string[0] = MyRandomIntegerBetween(65, 90); /// 'A' -> 'Z' in ASCII.
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:string encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Here's an alternative, that's really pretty much the same thing, but avoids the C string.

```
NSString *MyStringWithRandomUppercaseLetter(void) {
    unichar letter = MyRandomIntegerBetween(65, 90);
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&letter length:1] autorelease];
}
```

I prefer the explicit character encodings in the first approach, but they're both correct.

Comment: This doesn't handle character sequences at all, so I'm not sure why you feel this is superior.

Comment: Oh, I agree Chuck. The difference is that this code is explicitly limited to 'A'->'Z'. With the other approach, the caller needs to be aware of that problem in advance. Here, there's no opportunity of a caller of this function to make a mistake having to do with "characters" that need more than one code point.